# On click on every input field mail is sending

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a contact us form on my website. after clicking on every input field mail is sending, it should be like after hitting the **Submit** button mail should be sent. 
I have 4 fields in my form so it is sending total 5 mail, 1 mail with user inputs and 4 mails without user data.

> HTML code:

```
<form class="form" id="submit-event" name="myform" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Firstname2" name="name" required oninput="nameValidation()" placeholder="Enter your Name">
                <div class="name-error error">
                    Invalid name
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="phone">Phone</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" required oninput="contactValidation()" placeholder="Enter Contact Number">
                <div class="contact-error error">
                    Invalid contact number
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" required oninput="emailValidation()" placeholder="Enter your Email">
                <div class="email-error error">
                    Invalid email address
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Comments</label>
                <textarea class="form-control" id="comment" rows="5" cols="12" style="resize: none;" name="comments" required oninput="commentValidation()" placeholder="Enter your Comments here..."></textarea>
                <div class="comment-error error">
                    Maximum 500 characters are allowed
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row sub-btn">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <button type="submit" id="sub" name="submit" class="submit-btn" style="background-color: #707070;color: #ffffff; border: none !important;">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

> js code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#submit-event").click(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault(); 
                if (request) {
                    request.abort();
                } 
                var $form = $(this); 
                var $inputs = $form.find("input, button, textarea");
                if (flag_name == 1 && flag_email == 1 && flag_contact == 1 && flag_comment == 1) {  
                    var serializedData = $form.serialize(); 
                    // Fire off the request to /index.php
                    request = $.ajax({
                        url: "http://0to1designlabs.sankeysolutions.com/index.php",
                        type: "post",
                        data: serializedData
                    }); 
                    request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) { 
                        console.log("Form data submitted successfully.",request);
                        $.toast({
                            text: 'Submitted successfully',
                            icon: 'success'
                        })
                        document.getElementById("submit-event").reset();
                    });

                    request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        $.toast({
                            text: 'Error while submitting query',
                            icon: 'error'
                        })
                    });
                }
                else {
                    $.toast({
                        text: 'Some fields are invalid.',
                        icon: 'error'
                    })
                }
            });
        });
```

> And the PHP code :

```
<?php
try{
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $comments = $_POST['comments'];
    $to = "ahr@abc.com, asd.p@abc.com, aa.d@abc.com";
    $response = mail($to, 'Query from website',
      'Name : '.$name.
    'Phone : '.$phone.
    'email : '.$email.
    'comments : '.$comments.'');
    print_r($response); 
} catch(Exception $e){
    print_r($e);
}
?>
```

Can anyone help me with this, only one mail should be send.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are doing it wrong by calling click function on form, whenever you click on any item in form it triggers click event for you. 
submit-event is the form id, and sub is the button id, 
so the event you attached to it will do what it supposed to do. 
there are multiple ways to do it

```
   $("#submit-event").submit(function (event) {
        // code ...
   }
```

or like this way

```
$(document).on('submit','form#submit-event',function(){
   // code ...
});
```

or by using submit button via id

```
$("#sub").click(function (event) {
      // code ...
 }
```

Comment: `#submit-event` is my form id, i have tried `.submit()`. due to `.click()` on every input field toast msg is popping. but mail issue is still not resolve.

Comment: your mail code looks fine but try using $msg = the msg part,  and pass it to mail, may be the inline within mail function can cause issue,

Comment: I have already tried that ,using  `$message`, there is no issue in my php file.

Comment: check network tab , how many request are being sent? may be ajax is sending multiple request,

Comment: i have check that , only one request is going.

Comment: you need to debug it yourself because here it looks fine, remove print_r after mail, and also put if check for $_POST for empty, put print response at after try catch if you want, or use return. and is your ajax response success ?